# Databinding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged not firing with MultiBinding converter

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have set Multibinding on DataGridTextColumn Foreground property and what I want is whenever value of that cell changes I want it's converter to get executed, so to achieve that I tried  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged but still my converter is not firing when it's value is changed.

Below is the xaml snippet of it:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Item_Price , Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="Item Price" MinWidth="100" FontSize="16" Width="*">
     <DataGridTextColumn.Foreground>
       <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ItemPriceColorConverter}" Mode="TwoWay"   UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding Path="Item_Price" Mode="TwoWay"></Binding>
             <Binding Path="Item_ID" Mode="TwoWay"></Binding>
        </MultiBinding>
       </DataGridTextColumn.Foreground>
 </DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: First of all, all the `TwoWay` stuff on the MultiBinding and its child bindings doesn't make any sense. The data flow is only from the Item_Price and Item_ID properties to the Foreground property of the DataGridTextColumn, not the other way round. For the same reason `UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"` doesn't make sense on the MultiBinding. All you probably need to do is to raise a `PropertyChanged` event from the Item_Price and Item_ID property setters.

Comment: I am raising PropertyChanged event from the Item_Price, but still converter is not getting fired.